# Am I releasing this object too early after the animation?

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, memory-management

I have a UIView and I am animating it. 
The thing here is that I need to release `theView` once it is animated out.

```
originalRECT = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

if(theView)
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

    theView setFrame = originalRECT;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [theView autorelease];
    theView = nil;
}
```

So I know the code is setting theView to nil, but the animation `does finish ok` (No SIGABRT or something like that)
Or is there a callback function I can use to know that the view disappeared? How can I use a function like that in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things -

First of all if you want to be sure you can use:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                  delay:0.0 
                options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut 
             animations:^ {
                 //your animation
                  theView setFrame = originalRECT;
             } 
             completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                 //Animation finished you can release
                 [theView release];
 }];
```

second - why do you use autoRelease and not release?

```
[theView release];
```

Third - Just for w meeter you don't know. **USE ARC** it will make your life a bit easier. You can read more here [ARC tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1)

Comment: thanks, but I think ARC is not supported on iOS 4 on which I am working with

Comment: Arc does have a back support and you can develop for iOS 4 and above with ARC there are few thing to learn but they are easy as you get it.